# How to modify UIView properties for SwiftUI preview?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11

I have a `UIView` with 2 labels and one variable for binding like this:

```
var count: String? {
    get { viewCountLabel.text }
    set {
        viewCountLabel.text = newValue
        viewsTitleLabel.text = newValue == "1" ? "View" : "Views"
    }
}
```

and a `convenience init` like:

```
convenience init(count: String) {
    self.init()
    self.count = count
}
```

This view conforms to `UIViewRepresentable` as the following:

```
extension ViewCountView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = ViewCountView

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIViewType {
        UIViewType(frame: .zero)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<UIViewType>) {}
}
```

This works on the target as expected.

### - Question: How should I pass the count to the preview in live view?

I tried to pass the count on the initializer of the preview like the following but it doesn't work. I think I should pass the `count` in the form of `Context` somehow.

```
struct ViewCountView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ViewCountView(count: "0")
            ViewCountView(count: "12m")
            ViewCountView(count: "41234")
    }
}
```

**Please Note That** since I need more than 1 preview, I **can't** write  values **statically** inside `makeUIView` or `updateUIView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Simple wrapper struct - Works like a native:

```
struct <#NameOfTheWrapperView#>: UIViewRepresentable {

    typealias TheUIView = <#AnyUIView#>
    var configuration = { (view: TheUIView) in }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> TheUIView { TheUIView() }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: TheUIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) {
        configuration(uiView)
    }
}
```

## Completely customizable

```
ResponderTextField() {
    $0.backgroundColor = .red
    $0.tintColor = .blue
}
```

So `$0` points to the exact type and can be edited in anyway that you could in `UIKit` originally.

---

**Note That** I made it like a [gist](https://gist.github.com/MojtabaHs/8a2b9294de396c81aea1485d38c9b372), so you can easily copy and paste it in your code and just need to name it and define the original `UIView` type you need to use.

Comment: In this example, where would you put the $0.backgroundColor, etc.?

Comment: As the `configuration` argument like the example above. note that last argument is a function and can be written as a trailing closure.

Comment: So would I just use configuration per argument? For example, let's say I needed to pass a couple of values to my UIView. So configuration(uiView.value1) > new line > configuration(uiView.value2)

Answer (score 1):

Add a binding var to your `UIViewRepresentable`:

```swift
@Binding var count: String
```

Then change `updateUIView`:

```swift
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<UIViewType>) {
    uiView.count = count
}
```